# What's the minimum required to implement a custom XAML DependencyProperty in C++/WinRT?

Tags: uwp, winui-3, c++-winrt, winui

I'm writing WinUI 3 and UWP code, and I want to have a custom control with a DependencyProperty on it:

```xml
<local:MyControl Foo="Bar" />
```

I've read [Custom dependency properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/custom-dependency-properties) on MSDN, but there's a lot of content there. What's a short example with the minimum needed to implement a custom DependencyProperty in UWP or WinUI XAML, using C++/WinRT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my distillation of [Custom dependency properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/custom-dependency-properties), which is worth reading anyway since it explains a lot of the nuances of Dependency Properties:

### IDL

1. Add a static getter called `FooProperty` of type `static Microsoft.UI.Xaml.DependencyProperty`
2. Add a getter & setter called `Foo` of the actual type you want.

```
// MyControl.idl
runtimeclass MyControl : Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.UserControl
{
    MyControl(); // ... etc

    // Add these for each property
    static Microsoft.UI.Xaml.DependencyProperty FooProperty{ get; };
    String Foo;
}
```

### C++

1. Implement the member getter & setter using `DependencyObject::GetValue` and `SetValue` (which should be inherited via UserControl etc).
2. Implement the static DependencyProperty getter, which you can configure so your property can have a default value and a property-changed handler.
3. Make sure to `Register` your Dependency Property.

```cpp
// MyControl.h
namespace winrt::MyAppNamespace::implementation
{
    struct MyControl : MyControlT<MyControl>
    {
        // ...

        static winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::DependencyProperty FooProperty() const noexcept
        {
            return s_FooProperty;
        }
        auto Foo() const noexcept
        {
            return winrt::unbox_value<winrt::hstring>(GetValue(FooProperty()));
        }
        void Foo(winrt::hstring const& value)
        {
            SetValue(FooProperty(), winrt::box_value(value));
        }

    private:
        static winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::DependencyProperty s_FooProperty;
    }
}

// MyControl.cpp
using namespace winrt::MyAppNamespace::implementation;

MyControl::s_FooProperty =
    winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::DependencyProperty::Register(
        L"Foo",
        winrt::xaml_typename<winrt::hstring>(),
        winrt::xaml_typename<winrt::MyAppNamespace::MyControl>(),
        winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::PropertyMetadata{nullptr});
```

Done! You now have a working dependency property:

```xml
<MyControl Foo="Bar!" />
```

---

### Default value & changed handlers

- If you want a static "on change" callback, add a second parameter to the `PropertyMetadata` constructor.
- If you want a default value, change the first parameter to be your default value.

```cpp
// Value-changed callback
MyControl::s_FooProperty =
    winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::DependencyProperty::Register(
        L"Foo",
        winrt::xaml_typename<winrt::hstring>(),
        winrt::xaml_typename<winrt::MyAppNamespace::MyControl>(),
        winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::PropertyMetadata{nullptr, &MyControl::OnFooChanged});

// Value-changed callback & default value
MyControl::s_FooProperty =
    winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::DependencyProperty::Register(
        L"Foo",
        winrt::xaml_typename<winrt::hstring>(),
        winrt::xaml_typename<winrt::MyAppNamespace::MyControl>(),
        winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::PropertyMetadata{winrt::box_value(L"Default value"), &MyControl::OnFooChanged});
```

Note that the callback is static, not a member function. You'll have to fetch the actual instance:

```cpp
/*static*/ void MyControl::OnFooChanged(winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::DependencyObject const& d, winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs const& e)
{
    auto control{ d.as<MyAppNamespace::MyControl>() };
    auto newValue{ winrt::unbox_value<winrt::hstring>(e.NewValue()) };
}
```

### See also

- [Custom dependency properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/custom-dependency-properties)

Comment: Glad to hear that you've found a solution. You could accept you answer so it would help others who are facing the same issue.

Comment: I'll do so in 4 hours when I'm allowed to accept my answer 